# Im doing POST method to my API using EXPRESS ROUTER and this does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on API project for client.

The problem is using `POSTMAN` when i hit `POST` method the status I get is `Status: 500 TypeError`.

I tried put some data to my DATABASE manually so that I can check if my CRUD method is working. The `GET` method is working fine.

This is the `API` route i created:

```
const express = require('express')
const Client = require('../../models/Client')
const router = express.Router()

// Get Client
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Client.find()
    .sort({date: -1})
    .then(clients => res.json(clients))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err))
})

// Create Client
router
  .post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newClient = new Client({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      phone: req.body.phone,
    })

newClient
  .save()
  .then(client => res.json(client))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

module.exports = router
```

This is my Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const ClientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
})

module.exports = Client = mongoose.model("client", ClientSchema);
```

ERROR Message: `Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined`.

I tried all I can do, changing some code, hard coded some fields, but nothing works.
How to fix the error I get?

Comment: Did you send a request body containing the expected fields from Postman?

Comment: yes i did. `header` Key: content-type | Value: application/json `body`: raw `{"name": "samplename", "email": "sample@email.com", "phone": "0123123123123"}`

Comment: Hmmm, and you've made sure (debug, console.log) that `req.body` is sane inside the `.post('/')` route?

Comment: Use body-parser middleware, it may help you what are you looking for. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: of course, I don't see a body parser middleware either. Ha~ @Brajesh - fast fingers :-)

Comment: This is my body parser: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: You need to connect your Mongoose model to a mongodb database, something like this: mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});

Comment: mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("db connected..."))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));